# Compiler error when specifying main class in Akka microkernel?

Tags: scala, akka, microkernel

Here's my project definition in my `Build.scala`. When I go to run `sbt run` or `sbt dist` I get the same compiler error of `not found: value distMainClass`. It's quite annoying since I checked the akka-microkernel-plugin project to find `distMainClass` right there in release 2.0. I'm using 2.0.5, and it exists in 2.1.0, too.

```
lazy val ServiceKernel = Project(
    id = "tracker-kernel",
    base = file("."),
    settings = defaultSettings ++ AkkaKernelPlugin.distSettings ++ Seq(
      libraryDependencies ++= Dependencies.serviceKernel,
      distJvmOptions in Dist := "-Xms512M -Xmx2G -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:ParallelGCThreads=2",
      outputDirectory in Dist := file("target/s.Tracker-dist"),
      distMainClass in Dist := "namespace.ServiceKernel" //says not found
    )
  )
```

Any ideas as to the source of the issue? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have `import akka.sbt.AkkaKernelPlugin.distMainClass` or `import akka.sbt.AkkaKernelPlugin._` or something similar at the top of the file?

Comment: Hah! yikes! that was it. i probably would've caught that if i didn't tell eclipse to hide all of my imports. Thanks x2 for the help today LOL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we found out the issue was that you've forgot to import missing setting like:

```
import akka.sbt.AkkaKernelPlugin.distMainClass
```